# sqlite3 error when compiling with cl.exe from MVS 2013 with OMIT opition

Tags: c++, sqlite

When I try to compile the sqlite3.c and shell.c file to create a library, I write

`cl.exe /DSQLITE_OMIT_"one.of.the.option." sqlite3.c shell.c`

It returns an error:

```
sqlite3.c
sqlite3.c(155868) : error C2129: static function 'void sqlite3"name of the option choosen"(Parse *,Expr *,Expr *,Expr *)' declared but not defined
sqlite3.c(13360) : see declaration of 'sqlite3"name of the choosen option"'
 shell.c
  Generating Code...
```

For example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin>cl.exe -Os /DSQLITE_OMIT_ANALYZE sqlite3.c shell.c
    sqlite3.c
sqlite3.c(155868) : error C2129: static function 'void sqlite3Attach(Parse *,Expr *,Expr *,Expr *)' declared but not defined
        sqlite3.c(13360) : see declaration of 'sqlite3Attach'
shell.c
Generating Code...
```

This happens for all the OMIT options. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compile amalgamation version of the library (packaged as a single source file) and as stated in [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html) :

> Important Note: The SQLITE_OMIT_* options do not work with the amalgamation or with pre-packaged C code files. SQLITE_OMIT_* compile-time options only work correctly when SQLite is built from canonical source files.

See "Building The Amalgamation" in [how to compile](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html) section on how to build amalgamation with custom options:

> First construct an appropriate Makefile by either running the configure script at the top of the SQLite source tree, or by making a copy of one of the template Makefiles at the top of the source tree. Then hand edit this Makefile to include the desired compile-time options. Finally run:
>
> ```
>  make sqlite3.c
> ```
>
> Or on Windows with MSVC:
>
> ```
>  nmake /f Makefile.msc sqlite3.c
> ```

Comment: Ok,I've downloaded sqlite-autoconf-3081002.tar.gz,extracted it in cygwin and then I've ran ./configure at the top of the directory tree. Now i've the Makefile that has been created. Now,what part of the Makefile i've to edit in order to pass the SQLITE_OMIT option that i need?

Comment: There should be an empty `OPT_FEATURE_FLAGS` variable. Add required options there (e.g. `-DSQLITE_OMIT_ANALYZE`).

Comment: There is no OPT_FEATURE_FLAGS variable (nor something similar).I've also checked in all the Makefiles in the top of the source tree (not only the one generate by ./configure) but there isn't any.

Comment: I've found BUILD_CFLAGS,maybe it's this?

Comment: It seems you are building amalgamation again :). Try [sqlite-src-3081002.zip](https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-src-3081002.zip)

Comment: It is normal that the sqlite3.c file has the same size (5.392 kb) whatever OMIT option i insert in the Makefile? It will be reduced in size when i'll create the .lib?

Comment: @Azazel, Maybe there are cached artifacts left from previous build. Try to run `make clean sqlite3.c` or just `make clean` before build to remove them.

Comment: I've done something like 10 test and each time i've done a make clean. The lib is always 5mb. I think i should ask directly to sqlite3 support